# Javascript callbacks - why are these processed in different order?

Tags: javascript, callback

How come in this example, the 'second' function is exercised second:

```
<script>
function first (callback){
    alert ("I am first");
    callback();
}

function second (){
    alert ("I am second");
}

first(second);
</script>
```

But in this example, the second function is processed first.  Why does adding the () after calling the second make a difference....

```
<script>
function first (callback){
    alert ("I am first");
    callback();
}

function second (){
    alert ("I am second");
}

first(second());
</script>
```

Comment: storing vs Execution...

Answer (score 9):

Putting `()` after a variable holding a function will call that function.

`first(second);` calls `first` and passes the `second` function as an argument. `first` will then call `callback` which is the same as `second`

`first(second());` calls `second`, then calls `first` and passes the return value of `second()` as the argument. `first` will then call `undefined` (and error) because that is the return value of `second()`.